# Is there a way to mark parameters or properties as Serializable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, webforms

I am using

- C# 2012
- Visual Basic 2012 (VB 11)
- Asp.NET 4.5
- Visual Studio 2012

I have a class that stores data in the ViewState of a page.

```
Public Class State
    private _state as StateBag
    
    Public Property MyProp() as IEnumerable(Of MyType)
        Get
            Return getState("MyProp")
        End Get
        Set(value as IEnumerable(Of MyType))
            setState("MyProp", value)
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Function getState(key as String) as Object
        Return Me._state(key)
    End Function

    Private Sub setState(key as String, value as Object)
        Me._state(key) = value
    End Sub
End Class
```

And I have a model which is used to hold GridView Data

```
Public Class MyType
    Public Property Id As UInt64
    Public Property Value As String
End Class
```

Finally in the code-behind of my page, I get the data, set the DataSource on a GridView, call DataBind(), and lastly **I store the data in the ViewState**

```
Protected Sub drawGrid()
    Dim data As IEnumerable(MyType) = getData()
    MyGridView.DataSource = data
    MyGridView.DataBind()
    Me.State.MyProp = data
End Sub
```

If the `MyType` class is not marked with the `<Serializable()>` attribute, the GridView does not show any data.

**So I was wondering if there is any way to make it so I get a compiler error when I try to set a property that needs to be *Serializable***?

As an example

```
<Serializable()> Public Property MyProp...

OR

Set (<Serializable()> value as IEnumerable(MyType))...
```

If this is possible, the next time I forget to mark a class with "Serializable" the compiler will let me know, instead of me staring at my screen wondering: *"Why isn't any data showing???"*

**Here is the same code in C# that has the same issue**

- MyPage.aspx

  ```
   <%@ Page Title="MyPage" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.MyPage" %>

   <asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
       <h1>MyPage should show some MyType</h1>
       <asp:GridView
           ID="MyGridView"
           runat="server"
           DataKeyNames="Id"
           AutoGenerateColumns="false"
           EmptyDataText="No MyType Data"
           Caption="MyType Grid" >
           <Columns>
               <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" />
               <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" /> 
           </Columns>
       </asp:GridView>
   </asp:Content>
  ```
- MyPage.aspx.cs

  ```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;

   namespace WebApplication1
   {
       public class State
       {
           private System.Web.UI.StateBag _state;

           public IEnumerable<MyType> MyProp
           {
               get
               {
                   return (IEnumerable<MyType>)this.getState("MyProp");
               }
               set
               {
                   this.setState("MyProp", value);
               }
           }

           private Object getState(String key)
           {
               return this._state[key];
           }

           private void setState(String key, Object value)
           {
               this._state[key] = value;
           }

           public State(System.Web.UI.StateBag state)
           {
               this._state = state;
           }
       }

       [Serializable()] // This attribute MUST be here in order to save to the ViewState
       public class MyType
       {
           public UInt64 Id { get; set; }
           public String Name { get; set; }
       }

       public partial class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
       {
           private State _state;

           protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
               this._state = new State(this.ViewState);
               loadData();
           }

           protected void loadData()
           {
               IEnumerable<MyType> data = getData();
               MyGridView.DataSource = data;
               MyGridView.DataBind();
               this._state.MyProp = data;
           }

           private IEnumerable<MyType> getData()
           {
               var result = new List<MyType>();
               for (UInt64 i = 1; i < 11; i++)
               {
                   result.Add(
                       new MyType
                       {
                           Id = i,
                           Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")
                       }
                   );
               }
               return result;
           }
       }
   }
  ```

**NOTE the error** when the `[Serializable()]` attribute is removed

Comment: I don't see any `C#` here. Appears to be only `VB.NET`. I'd suggest removing the `C#` tag.

Comment: @Symon, thanks. I think I clarified that in an edit I just made. I also write in C#, so I could potentially translate a C# solution to VB for anyone having this issue.

Comment: I doubt there's any way to make this a compile-time error.  The best you might do is write an analyzer to catch it.

Comment: @Craig, that is a good idea, thanks. Right now I am using Visual Studio 2012 - which it appears does not support analyzers... Visual Studio 2019 seems to be the prerequisite as per: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix

Comment: Sorry, I completely missed the VS 2012 part of your question.  I think 2015 was the version where the compilers switched over to "Roslyn" and analyzers would be supported.  If you can swing the hard drive space to have both versions installed, you might be able to use something for VS 2019 as a check while still building for distribution in VS 2012.